# Why does it say "Name 'gray' can be not defined"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pycharm, aruco

This program was written by the co-op student before me at the company I am currently working for.  The project is to make a smart car kit [Kuman SM11] drive by showing the computer webcam different images.  In other words, autonomous driving where the car has no sensors.

One of the files he wrote were this one titled "arucoMarkerDistanceDetection".  It is quite a long file, so if the block of code I sent is not enough, let me know!

Below is one of the function definitions where the error occurs.  On the last line you can see `gray.shape[::-1]` and `gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` above it.  Why does Pycharm tell me that it may be not defined when it is defined only a few lines above?

I am pretty inexperienced at coding to begin with, so this has been a challenge.  Plus, trying to disect someone else's code is another task.  Further to this, I am using Pycharm, which I am still not 100% familiar with.

```py
for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # find the chess board (calibration pattern) corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7, 6), None)

    # if calibration pattern is found, add object points,
    # image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        # Refine the corners of the detected corners
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7, 6), corners2, ret)

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

```
    line 100, in <module>
        ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
    cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:3677: error: (-215:Assertion failed) nimages > 0 in function 'cv::calibrateCameraRO'
```

Comment: It would be undefined if images is empty. You should give it a default before the loop.

Comment: Note that PyCharm doesn't know that the loop will be entered. If you, however, *do* know that `images` will never be empty, then it's safe to ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

If "images" is empty, then the for loop will not run so the variable gray might not get initialized and after the loop, u are accessing gray which might not be present. Hence the code might break.